# Can i find all classes defined in the Standard Ruby Library?

Tags: ruby

I can obtain all classes as follows:

```
classes = ::Object.constants.select {|n| ::Object.const_get(n).class.to_s == "Class"}
```

This returns some data like this:

```
[:Object, :Module, ..., :SomeClass]
```

Unfortunately this will also pick up classes I have defined like `SomeClass`.

Is there any way that I can get only classes defined in the Ruby Standard Library?

My current workaround:

```
def getClasses()
  #It is anticipated that all classes up till RubyVM are default ruby classes, this will generally depend on ruby version.
  classes = ::Object.constants.select {|n| ::Object.const_get(n).class.to_s == "Class"}
  return classes.first(classes.find_index(:RubyVM)+1) 
end
```

Comment: `ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).to_a` will also give you an array of all classes, including your own.

Comment: Run your code before defining any classes yourself.

Comment: This is incredibly hacky and probably not correct :
`ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |o| !o.name.nil? }.select { |o| loc = Module.const_source_location(o.name) rescue nil; loc.nil? || loc.empty? || loc.first.include?("lib/ruby") && !loc.first.include?("rubygems") }` – oh, and it only works on Ruby 2.7 and above.

Comment: Also when you say "Standard Library" what do you mean? Ruby loads core classes in irb by default but ruby provides its own "Standard Library" whcih includes classes like `Date`, `OpenURI`, `BigDecimal`, `Benchmark`, just to name a few popular ones

Comment: @engineersmnky Difficult to say. There is a ruby runtime which I use which defines a set of non standard classes which all begin with prefix `WS` - I want to be able to target just these, however, in general these are non-standard classes. I know my case is easy to work around, but wanted to know if there was a better way. I think `Module.const_source_location` is probably the best option I have realistically.